# count of command get lost when do key mapping in vim

Tags: vim, paste

I have a key mapping for `p` in my vimrc file as below:
`noremap p <ESC>:set paste<CR>p:set nopaste<CR>`

The purpose of this key mappinng is to make sure the content from outside of vim can be pasted in its original format in paste mode. And restore it to nopaste mode after paste complete.

But when I run the following commands:

```
yy
5p
```

`p` is only executed once other than 5 times.
It looks like the count is missed from the key mapping.

Any way to pass the count in the key mapping?
Or how to fix this problem?

Comment: "Or how to fix this problem?" Get a proper Vim with clipboard support and get rid of that mapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fisrt `<ESC>` drops the count so it is no available later. Instead of `<ESC>` we would ignore and save count with `<c-u>` and access it later with `v:count1` variable like `:<c-u>set paste <CR>... v:count1 ...`.

But there is another problem: count will be lost after the first `<CR>`, so we want to rewrite the mapping as a single command. Chaining of commands may be done with `|`, but in mappings we should write `<BAR>` instead of `|`.

Here is the final mapping:

```
:noremap p :<c-u>set paste <BAR> :exe "normal! " . v:count1 . "p" <BAR> :set nopaste<CR>
```

`:exe "normal! "` is a fancy way to execute a command from evaluated string.